# JavaScript setTimeout Sinusbot

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm scripting for Sinusbot (a Bot for TeamSpeak) and want to write  a script that checks if an user has joined the channel.

Problem here: I want that the Script to do something after the user is 10 seconds in that channel!

I tried it with `setTimeout` but it didn't work.

What did I do wrong?

```
    if (ev.newChannel == channel_10m){
        //if someone joins channel_10m
        //wait 10 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (ev.newChannel == channel_10m){
                //check if user is in channel_10m
                //do somethink
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Sinusbot API: https://www.sinusbot.com/scripts/scripting3.html

Edit:

```
    var timeout;

sinusbot.on('clientMove', function(ev) {
    if (ev.newChannel == channel_10m) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            sinusbot.chatPrivate(ev.clientId, msg1);
        }, 10000);
    }
}

sinusbot.on('clientMove', function(ev) {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        sinusbot.chatPrivate(ev.clientId, msg2);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

I got it:

```
        if (ev.newChannel == achannel_entrance){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if ((sinusbot.getChannel(1267)['clients'][0]['id'] && ev.newChannel) == (sinusbot.getChannel(1267)['clients'][0]['id'] && achannel_entrance)){
                sinusbot.chatPrivate(ev.clientId, msg0);
                sinusbot.move(ev.clientId, bchannel_support);
            }
        }, 300000);
    }
```

Comment: your code looks fine, the setTimeout should work. Look at the javascript console for errors. Use the javascript debugger to see if the setTimeout is reached in your program.

Comment: There is no "error". I just need somethink that check if the User is after 10 second still in that channel.

Comment: Are you sure your program is entering the if block? Is `ev.newChannel == channel_10m` true?

Comment: as i said, your setTimout works, see: https://jsfiddle.net/rwh5c7m4/
the reason is that the code is not reached.

Comment: @josemigallas both works, but it checks both on the same time.

Comment: @Mario A Its for Sinusbot, its not the same JavaScript I guess?

Comment: I think we cannot help you without some more context. Could you make a fiddle with more code so we can reproduce it correctly? As @MarioA said your snippet is correct.

Comment: I see that I did wrong. ev.newChannel = If someone joins the channel. The first is right, but how I say if user is in channel?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is you want to check if the users is still conected you can try something like:

```
var timeout;

sinusbot.on("connect", ev => {
    if (ev.newChannel == channel_10m) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            doSomething();
        }, 10000);
    }
}

sinusbot.on("disconnect", ev => {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I think what you are doing now is cancelling the timeout whatever client is moving in or out. You should have track of different clients, let's try this:

```
// Dictionary for <clientId, timeout>
const timeouts = [];

// Event triggers when a client goes online or offline
// If client disconnects channel will be 0
sinusbot.on('clientMove', function(ev) {
    const clientId = ev.clientId;

    if (ev.newChannel == channel_10m) {
        timeouts[clientId] = setTimeout(() => {
            sinusbot.chatPrivate(clientId, msg1);
        }, 10000);

    } else if (ev.newChannel == 0 && timeouts[clientId]) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[clientId]);
        sinusbot.chatPrivate(clientId, msg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it, I just pasted it on my post :)

Comment: @ZarneXxX did my solution solved your problem? You should mark it as resolved then or you should add yourself and answer and mark it, so that everybody see the question is closed :)